# Match Strings which begin with X and end with Y?

Tags: java, regex

I want to match every file name which ends with `.js` and is stored in a directory called `lib`.

Therefore I created the following regular expression: `(lib/)(.*?).js$`.

I tested the expression `(lib/)(.*?).js$` in a [Regex Tester](http://regexpal.com/) and matched this filename: `src/main/lib/abc/DocumentHandler.js`.

To use my expression in Java, I escaped it to: `(lib/)(.*?)\\.js$`.

Nevertheless, Java tells me that my expression does not match.

Here is my code:

```
String regEx = "(lib/)(.*?).js$";
String escapedRegEx = "(lib/)(.*?)\\.js$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(escapedRegEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("src/main/lib/abc/DocumentHandler.js");

System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.matches()); // false :-(
```

Did I forgot to escape something?

Comment: match tries to match the whole string.`.*?(lib/)(.*?).js$` try this

Comment: matches would try to match the exact string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `Matcher.find()` instead of `Matcher.matches()` to check for subset of any string.

As per Java Doc:

- [Matcher#matches()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#matches%28%29)

  Attempts to match the **entire region** against the pattern.
- [Matcher#find()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#find%28%29)

  Attempts to find the next subsequence of the input sequence that matches the pattern.

---

sample code:

```
String regEx = "(lib/)(.*)\\.js$";
String str = "src/main/lib/abc/DocumentHandler.js";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);

if (matcher.find()) { // <== returns true if found            
    System.out.println("Matches: " + matcher.group());
    System.out.println("Path: " + matcher.group(2));
}
```

output:

```
Matches: lib/abc/DocumentHandler.js
Path: abc/DocumentHandler
```

Use [Matcher#group(index)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#group%28int%29) to get the matched group that is grouped by enclosing inside parenthesis `(...)` in the regex pattern.

---

You can use `String#matches()` method to match the **whole** string.

```
String regEx = "(.*)(/lib/)(.*?)\\.js$";
String str = "src/main/lib/abc/DocumentHandler.js";
System.out.println("Matched :" + str.matches(regEx)); // Matched  : true
```

**Note:** Don't forget to escape dot `.` that has special meaning in regex pattern to match any thing other than new line.

Comment: Your solutions works as well. Thank you for all the background information. My question was Java-specific and because you gave all the Java-specific infos, you will get the "accepted answer". All other working solutions will get an upvote! Thank you all. :)

Comment: I just changed the method (`find` instead of `matches`) in your code and it solved the problem. You can try without `Pattern` and `Matcher` as well using `String.matches()` method that accepts a regex pattern to match whole string.

Answer (score 2):

Try this RegEx pattern

```
String regEx = "(.*)(lib\\/)(.*)(\\.js$)";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("src/main/lib/abc/DocumentHandler.js");
```

It's working for me: [image]

Comment: Thanks for your solution! What's the name of the site you used for testing the RegEx? It looks great.

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer, try to add (^...$) Into your RegEx pattern. I'm writing from iPad so I can't test it in java((

Comment: Ok! I had to convert `\/` to `\\/` and then it worked. Thank you very much!

Comment: @BennyNeugebauer, damn, I did the same mistake a month ago )))

Answer (score 1):

Firstly you don't need to escape it, and secondly you are not matching the first part of the string.

```
String regEx = "(.*)(lib/)(.*?).js$";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regEx);
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("src/main/lib/abc/DocumentHandler.js");
```